# How to solve an ElementClickInterceptedException error?

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.co.uk/tennis/atp-singles/australian-open-2021/results')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
exit_loop = False
while not exit_loop:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        exit_loop = True
```

The first try/except block is to get rid of a 'privacy' banner that causes a `ElementClickInterceptedException`  error and it works fine. However, I'm still getting one of the following two similar errors on the next try/except block in the while loop:

```
Exception has occurred: ElementClickInterceptedException
Message: Element <a class="event__more event__more--static" href="#"> is not clickable at point (623,976) because another element <span class="loadingOverlay"> obscures it
```

or:

```
Exception has occurred: ElementClickInterceptedException
Message: Element <a class="event__more event__more--static" href="#"> is not clickable at point (623,976) because another element <div id="onetrust-banner-sdk" class="otFlat ot-iab-2 bottom vertical-align-content ot-buttons-fw"> obscures it
```

I've tried adding another try/except block for the second error:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='onetrust-banner-sdk']"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

However this doesn't work. I suspect I can't click this element so am on the wrong track...

As neither of the elements in the errors seem to be buttons I can click - how should I deal with them?

---

**Edit:**

I have updated the code to include scrolling:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.co.uk/tennis/atp-singles/australian-open-2021/results')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
exit_loop = False
while not exit_loop:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        exit_loop = True
```

However, I got each of the errors on the two runs I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jossy,

You need to scroll down till end of the page, before clicking on `show more matches`

code to scroll down :

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

and then you can have this code :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
```

You should launch broswer in full screen also :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

before loading the URL.

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.co.uk/tennis/atp-singles/australian-open-2021/results")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
exit_loop = False
while not exit_loop:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
        sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        exit_loop = True
```

Comment: Thanks! I presume I need to figure out what the 'scrolling elements' are? I can't just copy your code?

Comment: You can copy paste exact code, no need to change anything, place it just before while loop

Comment: Ok, thanks. Getting the same two errors - updated the OP with your additions

Comment: @Jossy : Can you try the updated code from update1 section, seems to be working fine on my local.

Comment: Works great and with Firefox too :) Amended slightly as it didn't need a 5 second gap

Comment: One slight snag - the errors return if I run it in headless mode. I assume this is because the window can't be maximised. Any way to run it in headless do you think?

Comment: no that `driver.maximize_window()` should maximize the window irrespective of headless or not.. try putting sleep little more .. and I would also like to know what is the exception

Comment: Ok - seems to be working fine this morning! Thanks again for all your help

Comment: No problem mate.